# How do I uninstall Visor?

Tags: macos, uninstall

[Visor](http://visor.binaryage.com/) (made by [Blacktree](http://www.blacktree.com)) is not a regular application, but it seems to be a plugin for Terminal.app in Mac OS X.  How do I uninstall such things?

Comment: Very nice program by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try removing the Visor.bundle from `~/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins`.  If that isn't enough (it wasn't for me), also remove from `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins`.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem (except I use [BinaryAge's](http://visor.binaryage.com/) version of Visor). Deleting the 
Visor plugin from ~/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins removed the Visor tab in the Preferences but I think there is some plist file somewhere that saves preferences. The consequence of that (in my case at least) is that I can't resize the first terminal window that opens because it get re-resized automatically (weird) but if I open new terminal windows and close the first one everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall SIMBL, automatically delete the visor...

start your terminal, go to preferences

under startup, set window to basic

restart ur terminal, and get the normal back